# Как запустить php скрипт через javascript/jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

У меня возникла нужда запустить php-скрипт через джаву или джейквери. Для того чтобы вы поняли что мне нужно представте себе такую картину...
Имеется таблица файлов в базе:

```
files
id | file_name   | file_publicname 
===|=============|================
 1 | file_1.xlsx | Смартфоны
 2 | file_2.xlsx | Ганритура
```

Имеется файл `index.php` в котором есть javascript ф-ция:

```
 <sctipt> $(document).ready(function(){get_file_btn("2")}); </script>
    ...
       function get_file_btn(id_file){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:     "event-listener.php",
                type:     "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                data: {"id_file_link":id_file},
                success: function(data) {
                    $(this).html(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert("Данні не відправлено. id_file_link="+id_file);
                }
            });
        }
```

И есть тот самый файл `event-listener.php` в который пересылается значение `id_file_link` методом POST:

```
if (isset($_POST['id_file_link'])) {
    file_download_btn($pdo,$_POST['id_file_link']);
}

function file_download_btn($pdo,$id) {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT file_name,file_publicname FROM files WHERE id=:id');
        $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
        foreach ($stmt as $row) {
            echo '<a class="download_excel" 
            href="files/'.$row['file_name'].'" download>Завантажити excel-файл '.$row['file_publicname'].'</a>';    
        }
    }
```

По идее данные отправляются правильно, но, не выводит ссылку на скачивание.
Помогите с решением проблемы.

Comment: По идее в Вашем случае если ссылка не выводится совсем, значит программа не заходит внутрь `foreach`, а значит `$stmt` - пуст. Проверьте в файле `event-listener.php`, действительно ли приходит нужный ID, и что находится в `$stmt` перед `foreach`.

Comment: можно сначала проверить вообще заходит ли в функцию `file_download_btn` можно использовать var_dump(). И открываем отладчик в браузере и смотрим во вкладке JS когда отправляется запрос что получаем в ответ. Так и можно отследить где ошибка.